# Неверное сравнение

Tags: javascript

Есть след код

```
    var date = new Date();
    var arr = [
             'Jan',
             'Feb',
             'Mar',
             'Apr',
             'May',
             'Jun',
             'Jul',
             'Aug',
             'Sep',
             'Oct',
             'Nov',
             'Dec'];
    var el = ["Jul 17 2019 09", 0.639, "1899"]
    var element = el[0];
      console.log(arr[date.getMonth()])
      console.log(element.slice(0, 4))
      console.log(typeof arr[date.getMonth()])
      console.log(typeof element.slice(0, 4))
      console.log(arr[date.getMonth()] === element.slice(0, 4))
```

Но при сравнении получаем false, хотя оба значения равны как по типу, так и по значению. В чем проблема? почему он не выдает true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы отрезаете 4 символа и туда попадает пробел после `Jul`. Надо отрезать либо 3 символа, либо делать `trim`

Answer (score 0):

Там y `el[0]` в конце пробел

```js
var date = new Date();
var arr = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct', 'Nov','Dec'];
var el = ["Jul 17 2019 09", 0.639, "1899"]
console.log(arr[date.getMonth()] == el[0].slice(0, 4).trim())
```

Answer (score -1):

В JS непосредственно сравнивать можно только примитивы. Все остальное всегда даст false

Comment: А почему `var test = 'test';
var test2 = 'test';
test === test2` выдаст `true` ?

Comment: Строки так сравнивать можно. А объекты и массивы нет.

Comment: А вы не заметили, что автор сравнивает именно строки?

Comment: Пойду съем свою шляпу ))